# getting data from query sql database to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have a problem with my code.
case like this:
I have a dropdown, if selected "personal" it appeared the new dropdown that contains the data that is retrieved from a database query, if selected "public", then the dropdown disappear.
HTML code like this:

```
<select name="use" class="dropdown" id="sender" onChange='changeSend()'>
     <option value=1>Public</option>
     <option value=0>Personal</option>
</select>

<div id='send2'></div>
```

Query like this:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from data where id_user = '$id_user' order by date asc");
    $i = 0;
    $id = array();
    $name = array();
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       //id from result database query
       $id[$i] = $data['id'];
       //name from result database query
       $name[$i] = $data['name'];
       $i++;
    }
?>
```

JavaScript code like this:

```
function changeSend() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("sender");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
   if (selectedValue==0) {
       $('#send2').html("<select class='dropdown'><option value='-id from result database-'>-name from result database query-</option></select>");
   } else { 
    $('#send2').html('');
   }
}
```

I dont know how to send value/result `($id[0],$name[0],$id[1],$name[1], etc..)` to javascript code(value and name in select options).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In javascript you have to make an `ajax call` to your php file:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("send2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","yourFile.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

And in your php file you have to `echo` your data in JSON format:

```
echo json_encode(array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name));
```

**UPDATE**
in your case use the following code:
(not tested)

php code:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from data where id_user = '$id_user' order by date asc");
    $i = 0;
    $options = array();
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $options[$data['id']] =  $data['name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($options);
?>
```

javascript code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      var select = '<select class='dropdown'>';

      for( var index in response ){
          select = select + "<option value='"+ index +"'>"+response[index]+"</option>";
      }
      select += "</select>";
      document.getElementById("send2").innerHTML= select;
  }
}
function changeSend() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("sender");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
   if (selectedValue==0) {
       xmlhttp.open("GET","yourFile.php",true);
       xmlhttp.send();
   } 
   else { 
     $('#send2').html('');
   }
}
```

**USING jQuery**

javascript code:

```
function changeSend() {
   var selectBox = document.getElementById("sender");
   var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
   if (selectedValue==0) {

       $.get("yourFile.php", function(data){
           var response = JSON.parse(data);
           var select = '<select class='dropdown'>';

           for( var index in response ){
               select = select + "<option value='"+ index +"'>"+response[index]+"</option>";
           }
           select += "</select>";

           $("#send2").html(select);
       });

   } 
   else { 
     $('#send2').html('');
   }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are using jQuery, the next time add the jQuery tag on the question, so we can provide jQuery based answers ;-)

Comment: on php code, why like this? `$options[$data['id']] =  $data['name'];`? I want to get data_id and data_name from result database query.

Comment: it's for build an array with the data loaded from database contained in the `$data` array

Comment: i mean -> `<option value='-id from result database-'>-name from result database query-</option>` , why you use `index` and `response[index]`?

Comment: Because the response is parsed in the variable `response` in the line `var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);`

Comment: why your solution can not be tried? i can't -> **if selected "personal" it appeared the new dropdown that contains the data that is retrieved from a database query, if selected "public", then the dropdown disappear.**

Comment: The provided php code has a SQL Injection. DO NOT USE

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be with an ajax call, anyway if you are declaring the script in the same page with the php, you can json encode the array with the options so that you will be able to access it into the javascript, like this:

```
var optionIds = <php echo json_encode($id); ?>
var optionNames = <php echo json_encode($name); ?>
```

Comment: how can i add var optionIds and optionNames to `$('#send2').html("<select class='dropdown'><option value='-id from result database-'>-name from result database query-</option></select>");` ?

Comment: To add javascript variable between string, use: 'yourstring' + variable + 'yourstring';